# Grouping GAWK output

Tags: gawk

Varlog kindly proivided a solution to a previous problem which looked at finding corresponding DISCHARGE Events to a INDUCT even and deleting this from an array.  This left me with all the items that have not yet been discharged to their destination.

The output of this script (below)

```
/REDIRECT_ITEM_REPLY/ {
    match($0, /itemId=<([^>]+)>/, ary1)
    match($0, /CscdestinationId=<([^>]+)>/, ary2)
    dest[ary1[1]] = ary2[1]
}

/DISCHARGE_VERIFIED/ {
    match($0, /itemId=<([^>]+)>/, ary1)
    delete dest[ary1[1]]
}

END {
    for (id in dest) {
        print dest[id]
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
17: CHU207
17: CHU207
35: CHU214
1: CHU001
157: FLY437
115: FLY424
108: FLY321
```

I would like to GROUP this information into something like :

```
CHU207  -  5
CHU001  -  10
FLY437  -   3
```

I was thinking about using the UNIQ command but just wondered how to incorporate this into the script, appreciate your help

I have tried a command line approach using uniq -c, but not sure if this is the best approach

```
gawk -f inductedNEW.awk item1.log | uniq -c
```

Appreciate your help

Phil

Comment: does the output fullfill your requirements? If so, then yes, this is the "best" approach in a unix/linux enviroment, where piping data to specialized programs is considered a "good thing". But this really is an off topic Q, so voting to close as "opinion-based". Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. 
 Good luck.

Comment: Shelter, thank you for your feedback appreciate the steer

Comment: `gawk` is just an implementation of `awk`. If you tag your questions with `awk` in addition to `gawk` you'll get vastly more people reading them and get multiple answers almost immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need pipes here. You have everything you need in your awk program.

Change the END part of your script to:

```sh
END {
    print "Detail:"
    for (id in dest) {
        print dest[id]

        group=dest[id];               # group = "123: ABC"
        sub(/^[0-9]+: */, "", group); # group = "ABC"
        groupCounter[group]++;        # counter++
    }
    print "Grouped:"
    for(group in groupCounter) {
        print group " - " groupCounter[group]
    }
}
```

If you don't need the detail part, just remove it.